# How to convert the data as following in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text-processing, spyder

I have some data in the following format in a csv file.

```
   Id   Category
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   B
    5   C
    6   d
```

I'd like to convert it into the below format and save it another csv file

```
Id  A   B   C   D   E
1   1   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   0
5   0   0   1   0   0
6   0   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dummy variables when not all categories are present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425961/dummy-variables-when-not-all-categories-are-present)

Comment: It is called One Hot Encoding and you can do that with sklearn OneHotEncoder() function

Comment: @ayhan That is a similar question, but how do I pass a .csv file where my data is present instead of directly passing the data? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `pd.get_dummies()`

```
>> df = pd.read_csv(<path_to_file>, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', header=0)

>> df
   Id   Category
0   1          A
1   2          B
2   3          C
3   4          B
4   5          C
5   6          d

>> pd.get_dummies(df.Category)
```

This will encode `Category` and give you new columns:

```
A B C d
```

But will not 'fix' d -> D and will not give you any columns that can not be deduced from the values you have in `Category`.

I suggest you check the solution posted in the comment earlier for that.

**EDIT**

```
# Load data from .CSV with pd.read_csv() as demonstrated above

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
  Category  Id
0        A   1
1        B   2
2        C   3
3        B   4
4        C   5
5        D   6

## One-liner for hot-encoding, then concatenating to original dataframe 
## and finally dropping the old column 'Category', you can skip the 
## last part if you want to keep original column as well.
In [14]: df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.Category)], axis=1).drop('Category', axis=1)

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   Id    A    B    C    D
0   1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   2  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2   3  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
3   4  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
4   5  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
5   6  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

## Write to file
In [16]: df.to_csv(<output_path>, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=None)
```

As you can see this is not the Transpose, only the result of the hot-encoding of the `Category` column is added to each row.

Whether Excel accepts the final data or not, there's not much you can do with Pandas about this, unfortunately.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please check updated answer. For a full solution I suggest you take a look at the link provided in the first comment under the original post as well.

Comment: I got a transpose of what I required and used df.transpose(). Thank you :)

Comment: @MohitVellanki If you found this answer useful then accept it please, so it's clear that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pivot table (updated to include .csv read/write functionality):

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'the path to your file'
df = pd.read_csv(path)

# your original dataframe
# Category  Id
# 0        A   1
# 1        B   2
# 2        C   3
# 3        B   4
# 4        C   5
# 5        D   6

# pivot table
df.pivot_table(index=['Id'], columns='Category', fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')

# save to file
df.to_csv('path\filename.csv') #e.g. 'C:\\Users\\you\\Documents\\filename.csv'
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
Category  A  B  C  D
Id                  
1         1  0  0  0
2         0  1  0  0
3         0  0  1  0
4         0  1  0  0
5         0  0  1  0
6         0  0  0  1
```

Comment: see update in solution: `df.to_csv('path/filename.csv') #e.g. 'C:\\Users\\you\\Documents\\filename.csv'`

Comment: The file is not being converted . It is just adding another Id column before the existing column.

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert'?  Do you want to replace 'd' with 'D'?

Comment: No. It is not being converted into binaries from mutli label.

Comment: What does `df` look like on your side when you run my above code?

Comment: Mine is a multi label classifier problem. It contains Id in one column and a multi label classifier name of string type

Comment: You should really post what that data looks like in your original question.  From the current question, it appears that every row has one `Id` and one `Category`.  If there are MULTIPLE categories within `Category`, I can update the answer.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/2Klpcsyqs.jpg
 This is the sample of my data. There are around 20 categories like that. And the data I'm working on is huge ( ~1 million entries).

Comment: Can a row have more than one category?? e.g. `MISSING PERSON, DRUG/NARCOTIC`

Comment: No. Every row has only one category.