# Dummy creation in pipeline with different levels in train and test set

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm currently exploring the scikit learn pipelines.
I also want to preprocess the data with a pipeline.
However, my train and test data have different levels of the categorical variable.
Example:
Consider:

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.Series(list('abbaa'))
test = pd.Series(list('abcd'))
```

I wrote a TransformerMixinClass using pandas

```
class CreateDummies(TransformerMixin):

def transform(self, X, **transformparams):
    return pd.get_dummies(X).copy()

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fitparams):
    return self
```

fit_transform yields for the train data 2 columns and for the test data 4 columns. So no surprise here, but not suitable for a pipeline

Similary, I tried to import the label encoder (and OneHotEncoder for the potential next steps):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(train)
le.transform(test)
```

which yields, not surprisingly, an error.

So the problem here is that I need some information contained in the test set.
Is there a good way to include this in a pipeline?

Comment: Can you get_dummies before you split train and test?

Comment: The data I have a from a kaggle competition split into train and test. But of course I could do this by simply concatenating those sets (the test set also has nans in different columns than the train set). I also fear that I have to do a pre preprocessing step here, I'm not yet sure if I like this ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use categoricals as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451867/2285236):

```
categories = np.union1d(train, test)
train = train.astype('category', categories=categories)
test = test.astype('category', categories=categories)

pd.get_dummies(train)
Out: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  0

pd.get_dummies(test)
Out: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great answer: For a more than one dimensional dataframe one should use ```train.apply(lambda x:x.astype('category', categories=categories), axis=0)```. Firstly, I was worried about the union1d function, since levels over all categories are caught. But this is not an issue. Do you see a way to avoid the apply here?

Comment: `astype('category')` only works for one dimensional arrays right now so either `apply` or an explicit for loop seems necessary.