# pandas categories new levels

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data, lightgbm

How does pandas categorical https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html handle new and unseen levels? I am thinking about a scikit-learn like setup. Currently, I have something like:
https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/5caff5236b4850d673b2c9b0799dc2ce

```
def: fit() 
  for each column:
   fit a label encoder:
def: transform()
  for each column:
     check if column was unseen
       yes(unseen) replace 
       no: label encode
```

but this is pretty slow.

Apparently, decision trees like xgboost or lightbm can directly handle categorical data, i.e. one would not need to fiddle around manually with this slow conversion.
But when looking at their code 
https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/lightgbm/sklearn.py#L532 they seem to use `LGBMLabelEncoder`which is a standard scikit-learn `LabelEncoder`.

I wonder how that can handle unseen data.

If a manual conversion is required would pandas.Categorical allow a quicker conversion - even if unseen levels are in the new data?

## edit

Please see https://github.com/geoHeil/pythonQuestions/blob/master/categorical-encoding.ipynb for an overview how I could not get scikit-learn's usual suspects to work.
Still looking for something more performant than my solution. Also lightGBM  https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/789 suggests to use custom encoding strategy.

Comment: Pandas.Categorical just fill them with Nan. Scikit-learn also dont handle new data, they will most likely be removed or replaced with Nan. Try using LabelEncoder with unseen data and you will get `ValueError: y contains new labels:`.

Comment: why this question got downvoted?? I guess a small reproducible data set and a desired one could help to understand the problem better...

Comment: @MaxU Maybe because in my opinion its more of a algorithm approach problem than a programming problem. This is a frequent issue in machine learning on how to handle unseen data and [Cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) is the right place for that.

Comment: @VivekKumar, i'd say it's in the grey zone (in between) ;-)

Comment: @VivekKumar if you want to move the question - that is fine.

Comment: I dont have enough privileges to do so on my own. If others feel this too, then only it can be moved. Thats just my opinion but I think this might get better attention there.

Comment: @VivekKumar, what about LabelBinarizer? Sure there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6723#issuecomment-323036777) but it works great on unseen data, but losing some information on the relations of the categorys

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 It maps all columns to 0 in a multilabel scenario and maps to first class in a binary scenario, so its upto the OP if he wants something like this. Which in my opinion brings us to whats the most used approach in most real situations when faced with this.

Comment: What do you mena with class 0? I.e. the first observation for this feature?

Comment: I just recalled, that I once askes a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804733/dummy-creation-in-pipeline-with-different-levels-in-train-and-test-set). The answer might be worth a look if you know all potential categories beforehand

Comment: The real solution is in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9151 and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9012 which are unfortunately not merged yet. LabelEncoder + OneHotEncoder or LabelBinarizer or CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x) are all possible workarounds (though none is great).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a pandas solutin, but it works probably best with sklearns [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
df= pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c','a']})
lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(df["A"])
lb.transform(df["A"])

[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','d']})
lb.transform(df2['A'])
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

So we see that 'd' is essentially mapped to neither 'a','b' or 'c'.
Note however, that there is a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6723#issuecomment-323036777) which probably will be resolved in one of the next sklearn releases.

The LabelBinarizer is fit during training and recalls the values passed to it. New values get mapped to all zeros. It might be more feasible do write a transformer (as seen here before the edit) using pandas get_dummies.

This could be quite straightforward due to name matching of columns. Fit in the first step and store the column names, than just transform in the transformstep, but only keep column names that you identified in fitting (potentially adding zome zero columns if training levels are not present in the test set). Then you are done ;)

Comment: But that is lacking the focabulary - you do not guarantee that a second df with potentially unseen categorical levels or levels in different ordering to be encoded properly.

Comment: You are right, the lack of ordering might be missing, however, when working on columns with discrete values, new categories/values will be mapped to zero in every column.

Comment: Regarding ordering, if df_1 contains a,b and this is mapped to 1,2 and df_2 contains b,c this should be mapped to 2,0 so it should not be a problem? Or do I misunderstand this?

Comment: I'll add an example in the answer, give me a moment, and there seems to be a mistake in the fit function ;)

Comment: updated it and removed the previous class instead using the labelbinarizer from sklearn. However, if you are interested I could also construct a related solution with pandas `get_dummies` (or try it on you own)

Comment: Can the binarized handle multiple columns at the same time?