# Duplicating pandas.get_dummies columns from train to test data

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable, train-test-split, feature-engineering

I have two dataframes, `train` and `test`. They both have the same exact column names which contain categorical string features.

I'm trying to map these features to dummy variables in the training set, train a regression model, then do the same exact mapping for the test set and apply the trained model to it.

The problem I came across is, since `test` is smaller than `train`, it happens to not contain all the possible values for some of the categorical features. Since `pandas.get_dummies()` seems to just look at `data.Series.unique()` to create new columns, after adding dummy columns in the same way for `train` and `test`, `test` now has less columns.

So how can I instead add dummy columns for `train`, and then use the same exact column names for `test`, even if for particular features in `test`, `test.feature.unique()` is a subset of `train.feature.unique()`? I looked at the [pd.get_dummies documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but I don't think I see anything that'll do what I'm looking for. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451867/2285236

Comment: Thanks that looks like it'll work, trying it now :)