# Include more columns with get_dummies()

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have the following lists:

```
vocab = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

With the following code, I would like to get an encoding that creates a one-hot-encoding for list 1, but includes all the items from vocab.

```
import pandas as pd
encoding1 = pd.get_dummies(data= list1, columns= vocab)
encoding2 = pd.get_dummies(data= list2, columns= vocab)
```

I want the output:

```
encoding1 =      a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
              1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
              2  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
              3  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
              4  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
              5  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0

encoding2 =      a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
              1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
              2  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 
              3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
              4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
              5  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

However, I get the output:

```
encoding1 =      a   b   c   d   e   
              1  1   0   0   0   0  
              2  0   1   0   0   0  
              3  0   0   1   0   0  
              4  0   0   0   1   0   
              5  0   0   0   0   1   

encoding2 =      f   g   h   i   j   
              1  1   0   0   0   0  
              2  0   1   0   0   0  
              3  0   0   1   0   0  
              4  0   0   0   1   0   
              5  0   0   0   0   1
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: It is similar to the one asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425961/dummy-variables-when-not-all-categories-are-present

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the dummies to data frames then we assign the columns to `vocab` then lots of `NaN`'s will show up in the new columns then use the pandas `fillna` function for data frames and in the parameters we write `0` so it converts all the `NaN`'s to `0`:

```
encoding1 = pd.get_dummies(data= list1)
encoding2 = pd.get_dummies(data= list2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(encoding1, columns=vocab)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(encoding2, columns=vocab)
print(df1.fillna(0))
print(df2.fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
df1
   a  b  c  d  e    f    g    h    i    j
0  1  0  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0  0  1  0  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0  0  0  1  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0  0  0  0  1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
df2
     a    b    c    d    e  f  g  h  i  j
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1  0  0  0  0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0  1  0  0  0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0  0  1  0  0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0  0  0  1  0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try

```
vocab_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data= vocab)

encoding1 = vocab_dummies.iloc[0:5,:]
encoding2 = vocab_dummies.iloc[5:vocab_dummies.shape[0],:].reset_index(drop=True)

encoding1
Out[67]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0

encoding2
Out[68]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```